# How to save HTMLParser output to a string?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I'm trying to save output from the HTMLParser class as a string to be further manipulated down the line by my own program. I tried to simply write

```
manipulateString = parser.feed(html_string)
```

but that returned an error message. I've looked into using cPickle but having to create another file just to retrieve parser output seems unwieldy.

How should I go about writing `parser.feed(html_string)` to a string?

Comment: "that returned an error message" <-- But the error message is a secret? :-)

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: `parser.feed()` doesn't return anything but `None`, did you read the documentation?

Comment: @gdlmx yea sorry just realized that I wrote the question incorrectly. Is there any way to get it to return the feed?